# android change setText

Tags: android, settext

I'm developing an android application.. I want to set a text in an editText based on the user's entered keys from softkeyboard.

How can I change the text content before it is set in the EditText in android application???

Answer (score 2):

With [TextView.setOnEditorActionListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener%28android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener%29) you can be notified when an action is performed in the EditText.

Comment: it is editText and I want to change the text before it is set

Comment: I don't want to use et.setText

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work 
because using setText will cause problems to me

Comment: I want to change the text without using et.setText

Comment: This lets you modify the text after it is set so I do not understand what the issue is. You are supposed to use beforeTextChanged so you can understand what is about to change, if that is important, and finish up with afterTextChanged. If you are unable to use setText() then I feel you have a deeper issue and are likely doing something less than desirable. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html